# High fps on animation with translucent background

Tags: android, android-animation, frame-rate

I created an application that has a translucent (`#7F00FF00`) background.

Now the bottom half of the `Activity` is a `FrameLayout` where I set a new Fragment with the following animation:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

Now this works fine, but the problem is the frame rate. Because of the translucent background it has a low fps. But the animation will be very smooth when I make the background fully transparent.

How can I improve the fps of this animation? Is there an other way to make the background translucent without losing frames?

[Android 4.0 on a Tegra2 device]

Comment: Have you set `android:hardwareAcceleration` to true in your Manifest? Another thing you can try is to set `animationCache` to true or use `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` on your views.

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo hardwareAcceleration is true. And the animationCache doesn't help and `"The animation cache is enabled by default."`

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Google 2012 video 'For butter of worse' @ 54:34](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8m9sHdyXnE)

Even though JellyBean has a much smoother feel to animation it seems this is one of the things Android hasn't yet been optimized for, as even Chet Haase and Romain Guy recommend to disable translucency when animating (but telling it's fine for static purposes).

edit: [facepalm] so maybe i should have watched another few minutes of that movie...

Comment: Yes, I have seen that one. But your edit says enough :) I guess we just need Jelly bean :)